# Boost Graph Library: Deleting an edge while using an iterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph-theory

Currently I am trying to implement a Girvan Newman Algorithm for a class project using boost graph library in c++.

At the moment, edges and vertices are being added fine, but I am having an issue removing edges. I am using an iterator to add my edges, and am now trying to remove them. Everything functions as expected until I try to remove an edge, and then I hit a segfault. I have tried removing the edge using the conditional remove_edge_if() and tried some of the other boost options - still having the same issue.

```
enum {A, B, C, D, E};
    num_vertices = 5;

    //writing out edges in graph

    typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;
    Edge edge_array[] = {
            Edge(A,B),
            Edge(A,D),
            Edge(C,A),
            Edge(D,C),
            Edge(C,E),
            Edge(D,E)
    };
    const int num_edges = sizeof(edge_array)/sizeof(edge_array[0]);

    //declare a graph object
    Graph g(num_vertices);

    //add the edges to the graph object
    for(int i=0;i<num_edges;i++){
        add_edge(edge_array[i].first, edge_array[i].second, g);
    }


    //actual algorithm starts here

    //get property map for vertex indices
    index = get(boost::vertex_index, g);

    //calculate all centrality values and store in vector betweenness
    calcCentrality();

    //set up iterators to run through all edges
    boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator ei, ei_end;
    boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator loc;

    std::tie(ei, ei_end)=edges(g);
    for(int i=0;i<num_edges;i++){
        std::cout << "(" << index[source(*ei, g)] << "," << index[target(*ei, g)] << ") ";
        ei++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::tie(ei, ei_end)=edges(g);

    int max_B = 0;
    boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor max_B_edge1, max_B_edge2;

    //iterate through all edges-1
    for(int i=0;i<num_edges-1;i++){
        //check betweenness centrality of edge i
        int BC = betweeness[i];
        if(BC > max_B){
            max_B = BC;

            max_B_edge1 = source(*ei, g);
            max_B_edge2 = target(*ei, g);
        }
        ei++;
    }

    boost::remove_edge(max_B_edge1, max_B_edge2, g);
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::tie(ei, ei_end)=edges(g);
    for(int i=0;i<num_edges;i++){
        std::cout << "(" << index[source(*ei, g)] << "," << index[target(*ei, g)] << ") ";
        ei++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Any guidance on how to resolve this, or a new approach would be extremely helpful. I think the issue is with my iterator

Comment: Why do this "std::tie(ei, ei_end)=edges(g);" and then do this "for(int i=0;i<num_edges-1;i++)"?  Google "boost graph iterate over edges" to get suggestions for much better ways of doing this.

Comment: You are NOT using an iterator to delete the edge.  You are using two vertex descriptors.  So, your question, as stated, makes no sense.

Comment: @ravenspoint I tried my best anyways. It took the usual copious amounts of time, but hey :)

Answer (score 3):

The bigger problem is that you are indexing `betweenness` by an integer `[0, num_edges)`. This doesn't make a lot of sense unless `betweenness` is actually an edge centrality map (not the vertex centrality map, or just "centrality map").

But that is making things weirder, because that would suggest an associative container like `map<edge_descriptor, double>` instead of a `vector<>`, because `edge_descriptor` is not an integral type.

Of course, one can paper over this by creating an explicit `edge_index` property/map and projecting through that to a integral-indexed container, e.g.

```
 std::vector<double> betweenness(num_edges(g));
 auto edge_id_map = get(boost::edge_index, g); // or assumed externally supplied?
 auto edge_centrality_map = boost::make_safe_iterator_property_map(
     betweenness.begin(),
     betweenness.size(),
     edge_id_map);
```

Now, if that were the case, one has to wonder why the same map is not used to access the betweenness by descriptor... instead of implicitly recalculating an edge index again in a loop-variable (`int i`). That is unsafe **especially** since you're modifying the edges, so re-running the loop will calculate different `i` for each edge! Oops.

> Instead, I'd make betweenness associative, indexed by edge-descriptor. Of course, I can't show the relevant changes, because `calcCentrality` is missing. Even `betweenness` is missing (which by the way suggests that it must be a global variable? Not a very robust idea if so).

Let's assume for a moment that you have `edge_centrality_map` defined as above, or, in my preferred approach, like this:

```
// more stable idea:
std::map<Graph::edge_descriptor, double> betweenness;
auto edge_centrality_map = boost::make_assoc_property_map(betweenness);
```

Now the whole... mess with the loop could be replace with:

```
std::map<Graph::edge_descriptor, double> betweenness;
auto edge_centrality_map = boost::make_assoc_property_map(betweenness);

while (num_edges(g)) {
    auto ee         = edges(g);
    auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(
        ee.first, ee.second, [ecm = edge_centrality_map](auto a, auto b) {
            return ecm[a] < ecm[b];
        });

    remove_edge(*max, g);
    print_edges();
}
```

For good measure I used `minmax_element` to show off the convenience of using standard algorithms here. We use the lambda to "simply" project through the centrality map. No manual juggling with loop variables and translating to vector indexes. This is less work, but more importantly less room for error.

Here's the code presented modernized and showing the suggested approach:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TzWc15oG1)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/betweenness_centrality.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<>;

int main() {
    enum { A, B, C, D, E, N /*==5*/ };

    Graph g(N);

    auto print_edges = [&g] { // helper to avoid repeating code
        for (auto e : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
            std::cout << e << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    };

    // add the edges to the graph object
    for (auto [s, t] :
        std::array{std::pair{A, B}, std::pair{A, D}, std::pair{C, A},
                    std::pair{D, C}, std::pair{C, E}, std::pair{D, E}}) //
    {
        add_edge(s, t, g);
    }

    print_edges();

    // actual algorithm starts here

    // get property map for vertex indices
    auto index = get(boost::vertex_index, g);

    // calculate all centrality values and store in vector betweenness
    // calcCentrality();
    //std::vector<int> betweenness(num_edges(g)); // JUST GUESSING

    // more stable idea:
    std::map<Graph::edge_descriptor, double> betweenness;
    auto edge_centrality_map = boost::make_assoc_property_map(betweenness);

    while (num_edges(g)) {
        auto ee         = edges(g);
        auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(
            ee.first, ee.second, [ecm = edge_centrality_map](auto a, auto b) {
                return ecm[a] < ecm[b];
            });

        boost::remove_edge(*max, g);
        print_edges();
    }
}
```

Prints dummy output (because the `betweenness` is defaulted to `0.0` for each edge):

```
(0,1) (0,3) (2,0) (2,4) (3,2) (3,4) 
(0,1) (0,3) (2,0) (2,4) (3,2) 
(0,1) (0,3) (2,0) (2,4) 
(0,1) (0,3) (2,0) 
(0,1) (0,3) 
(0,1)
```

### BONUS

In fact, the loop is not very optimal, because instead of repeatedly finding the maximum element of a container, just to remove them can be thought of as sorting, and then removing edges in order.

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/GsndKEd3s)**

```
auto [e_begin, e_end] = edges(g);
std::vector ascending(e_begin, e_end);
std::stable_sort(begin(ascending), end(ascending), edge_compare);

while (not ascending.empty()) {
    remove_edge(ascending.back(), g);
    ascending.pop_back();
    print_edges();
}
```

Which gives the same output, just much quicker.

> *Also note that if your chosen `edge_centrality_map` suffers from
> index/iterator/descriptor or reference invalidation in some way on the
> `remove_edge` operation, this is safer, because it **only** depends on
> the stability of edge descriptors in your chosen `Graph` model.*

In fact, you might not even need/want to remove the edges "physically" to save time and work. After all, you know which edges to leave out when printing.